# How to split e-mail Subject and Body in python using smtplib

Tags: python

Somhow when the email is sent it only shows the Subject (%s dues unpaid.)
I believe something with the formatting is not right, but can't figure out.
Any help is appreciated.

Nick

```
for name , email in unpaidMembers.items():
    body = "Subject: %s dues unpaid. \nDear %s, \nRecords show that you have not paid dues for %s. Please make this payment as soon as possible. Thank you!" % (latesMonth, name, latesMonth)
    sendmailStatus = smtpObj.sendmail(FromEmail, ToEmail, body)
```

Answer (score 0):

Uppsss, I found out that it needs 2 '\n\n' to separate the subject from the body.

Thanks to Tim Roberts